# Input validation not working with v2.ODataModel in contrast to JSONModel

Tags: odata, sapui5

In the current project, I have a [SimpleForm](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.layout.form.SimpleForm/) on a view. Binding a JSONModel on this view, the `validateValue` function is working fine on my input field. The constraints on the input field are defined as follows:

```xml
<Input value="{
  path: '/carrId',
  type: 'sap.ui.model.type.String',
  constraints: {
    // ... 
  }
}"/>
```

Changing the model to an `ODataModel` doesn't fire the `validateValue` and the field is not marked with red if the constraints are not matched.

The view is registered at the message manager.

Do I have to implement the validation by implementing a `change` event or where is the mistake?

Comment: Just to let you know, I updated my answer below which might explain the actual reason why it didn't work when you changed from JSONModel to an ODataModel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Replace <s>`sap.ui.model.type.String`</s> with the type corresponding to the EDM type of your `carrId`. E.g. with [`sap.ui.model.odata.type.String`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.type.String) if it has the `Type="Edm.String"` in metadata. Note that the `constraints` settings are also different.
2. In order to actually allow transferring the user input from the UI back to the model, and thus triggering `parseValue` and `validateValue` automatically, the **binding mode needs to be `TwoWay`** (The default binding mode of `v2.ODataModel` is `OneWay`*).

   - Open `manifest.json`
   - Set `/sap.ui5/models/<modelName>/settings/defaultBindingMode` to `"TwoWay"`:

     ```json
     {
       "dataSource": "MyV2ODataSource",
       "settings": {
         "defaultBindingMode": "TwoWay",
         "preliminaryContext": true
       },
       "preload": true
     }
     ```

---

* See *[Binding Modes: One-time Binding, One-way Binding, and Two-way Binding](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/topic/68b9644a253741e8a4b9e4279a35c247#section_BindingModes)*

Comment: A bit late but I'm experiencing the same issue: parseValue and validateValue are not called when I change from a JSONModel variable (validated against type sap.ui.model.type.Float) to an oDataModel (validated against type sap.ui.model.odata.Decimal). I ended up firing both the functions on the change event of the input but I'm not happy with this solution since I feel I'm missing something... Should I open a different thread? I can't find any topic related..

Comment: @Cmdd I guess it's because you've assigned an invalid type. It should be `'sap.ui.model.odata.type.Decimal'` (In your case, the part `.type` is missing). UI5 only recently started logging errors for such typos: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/2501. I.e. if you change the bootstrap CDN to  `https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js`, you should see the corresponding error in the console.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misspelled the type in my question but in the code I use the right 'sap.ui.model.odata.type.Decimal' type :-(

Comment: @Cmdd https://jsbin.com/wujoduk/edit?js,output works (If value > 999 is typed, the valueState becomes red). If that doesn't help, I think a new question with an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be very helpful so that other contributors can also take a look.

Comment: Many many many thanks for the jsBin but maybe I was unclear: your example works also for me when I bind a value from a JSONmodel as you did. The problem occurs only when I bind a value from an oData model, let's say the unnamed model, with data coming from tha backend! I'm really considering to open a new question but I'm a bit in a hurry right now :-)

Comment: @Cmdd Did you set the `defaultBindingMode` to `"TwoWay"`? In `JSONModel`, it's already two-way by default but `v2.ODataModel` one is `"OneWay"`. This might explain why `parseValue` and `validateValue` are not called when switching to ODataModel.

Comment: There it is! What a newbie error... I think I took too literally "summer brain vacation". Many thanks, again!

Comment: @Cmdd No, it's not a newbie error. I should've come to that conclusion earlier. Thank you too! This is an important note to add to my answer.